# Pass PHP Class Without Instance

Tags: php, types

I've constructed:

- An IDbContext interface for database operations
- A DbContext abstract class representing a generic database connection
- An IDomain interface for common domain model operations
- Several concrete implementations of IDomain, in this example Domain
- Corresponding concrete implementations of DbContext which should have IDbContext behaviors determined by the concrete implementations of IDomain with which they are created.

  ```
  abstract class DbContext implements IDbContext {
      function __construct($host, $db, $credentials, IDomain $domain)

      public function Get($id){
      //base implementation determined by IDomain interface behavior
      }   
  }

  class DomainContext extends DbContext {
  parent::__construct($host, $db, $credentials, Domain $domain)

      public function Get($id){
      //overrides or extends base implementation
      //determined by Domain class implementation of IDomain interface
      }
  }
  ```

I have read that generics don't seem to be coming to PHP until version 7 at least, so I've given up on that route. However, it would be an ideal alternative if instead of having to ask for the interface or an instance (as in the previous example) of the Domain model class in question, I could pass just the class. However, I don't know if this is legal to do in PHP, or whether there's a better solution of which I'm unaware.

Comment: I had written a previous explanation comparing to a technique for Type comparison in C# but removed it. I remove the corresponding tag, thanks for reminding me it was there.

Comment: it's not quite clear what you want to achieve. What's the behaviour you would like to have?

Comment: I'd like concrete implementations of DbContext to be bound to a concrete implementation of IDomain. Since I can't use generics for this purpose, I'm fine with using the constructor to achieve this. However, I'd like the constructor signature to be based on the specific concrete implementation *class* of IDomain, not IDomain or an instance of the concrete implementation.

Like:
parent::__construct($host, $db, $credentials, Domain);

Does that clarify?

Comment: well if you wanna get smth like as described in java [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Generic_class_definitions) the way this can be done (actually just workarounded) in PHP (at least one of the ways) is to pass the names of the classes that are to be accepted to the constructor and moving your injections to setters (or initters, as Mr.Fowler would name them). Then inside setters you will be able to check what types were tried to be injected.

Comment: still it will have a drawback of unability of proper linting, you will get an error only at runtime. I would stay with interface type hinting )))